# Add Row to Marketing Cloud Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm trying to add a row to a simple data extension with email and name as fields using the following: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/insertDataExtensionIDAsync.htm

I have the following code (accessToken is generated in another function)

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
   url:"https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/async/dataextensions/external_key_of_DE_here:key/rows",
   method:"POST",
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ accessToken
   },
   body: '{"items":[{"email":"test@test.com", "name":"test"}]}'
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

however, i keep getting an error:

```
{ 
     "message":"Internal Server Error", 
     "errorcode":0, 
     "documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm"}
```

The authentication is working but for some reason nothing is passing through to the DE.

Comment: what's the value of your Data Extension's customer/external key?  You'll need to replace `external_key_of_DE_here` with that value.

Comment: Is field Email use the "EmailAddress" datatype.  I wonder if "test@test.com" if failing List Detective and therefore won't insert.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs external_key_of_DE_here is just a replacement for the key i have.

Comment: @DavidDevoy field Email is datatype EmailAddress.

Comment: I ran a sample using exactly what they have listed as an example in my environment and still got the same error. This may be an issue with SFMC - have you put in a ticket? As a quick fix, I would look into using the upsert in dataevents (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm) as I know this works.

Comment: @Gortonington the dataevent works indeed, but the problem is that that call requires the DE to have a primary key which is not the case with the DE i am working with.

Comment: darn! that stinks. I think your best bet is through SFMC global support then, unfortunately. Please post what they say back on here as I am super curious on why this documented call does not function.

Comment: On various occasions SFMC support has directed to come for support here so hopefully some genius here has the solution :)

Comment: Yeah, I have had them reference my own answers/questions to me multiple times. This sounds like an issue with their system, not the call. I mean I literally copied their example exactly and it failed.

Comment: They updated the documentation: "We limit these resources to accounts that are enabled via a custom setting. Marketing Cloud can enable this setting at the enterprise, account, or custom object level. Reach out to your account representative to enable these resources in your account"

Answer (score 1):

@findev

try formatting your url to:
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:external_key_of_DE_here/rows